# Add column with condition either "hot" or "cold" in relation to temperature in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column with a condition "if Temperatur > 80 show hot in rows else show cold in the rows"

this is my code:

```
tempcat_aq <- aq %>% group_by(aq$Temp) %>% mutate(TempCat = if(any(aq$Temp > 80) "hot" else "cold"))
```

I'm using the airquality dataframe build-in in R and the dplyr library.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: It seems that you need `ifelse` or `if_else`, rather than `if any ... else ...`.

Comment: May I ask why you group the data here?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$` while using `dplyr` pipes, it is not needed and it breaks the grouping.

```
library(dplyr)
aq <- airquality

tempcat_aq <- aq %>% 
               group_by(Temp) %>% 
               mutate(TempCat = if(any(Temp > 80)) "hot" else "cold")
```

Answer (score 2):

As mt1022 suggests, a simple base R `ifelse` should suffice:

```
aq$tempcat <- ifelse(aq$Temp > 80, 'hot', 'cold')
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any difference on efficiency whether using ifelse or if and else separately, or is is just a shorter way of writing the code?

Comment: I never did a comparison on a huge data set.  But the vectorization paradigm of R points to the simple single line `ifelse` solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifelse` in your `dplyr` workflow with the suggestions of Ronak and SteveM

```
library(dplyr)

tempcat_aq <- aq %>% 
  group_by(Temp) %>% 
  mutate(TempCat = ifelse(Temp > 80, "hot","cold")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter without using `$`:

```
library(dplyr)

tempcat_aq <- airquality %>% 
              mutate(TempCat = ifelse(Temp > 80, "hot", "cold"))
```